# How do you score the Mayor in a city with no pennants?

Tags: carcassonne

We played our first games with the Abbey & Mayor expansion tonight, and ran across a scoring question that's not precisely covered by the rules.  The rules are pretty simple:

1. The Mayor counts as a meeple, so you can't play him where another meeple is already present.
2. The Mayor counts as one follower for each pennant in the city.

What happens if a city with no pennants is closed (or the game ends) and the only meeple in the city is a Mayor?  Does that player score zero points for the city?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No points are scored.**

From the [Carcassonne Annotated Rules](http://www.carcassonnecentral.com/forum/index.php?topic=587.0) p58 (note 161)

> **Question**: Blue has a mayor in a city with no pennants. Does the city count as occupied? And if
>   so, when the city is scored, will blue score points? Answer: The city is occupied. The mayor has no
>   ‘strength’, so he counts as if there is no follower, and scores no points.

Comment: Good, that's how we played it.